# adapt an acoustic model using "sphinx4" only

Tags: cmusphinx, sphinx4, pocketsphinx

Is it possible to adapt an acoustic model using "sphinx4" only? I have already checked the website but the commands mentioned are for pocketShphinx "[Adapting the default acoustic model](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialadapt)".
I have also checked some other solutions but all those used pocketsphinx.

Comment: what are the other solutions you checked ? "Adapting the default acoustic model" doc mentioned the procedure to adapt acoustic model for both sphinx4 and pocketsphinx. For sphinx4 you can adapt "continuous" model.

Comment: @G10DRAS i followed the tutorial. when i try to run the command                   bw  -hmmdir en-us  -moddeffn en-us/mdef.txt   -ts2cbfn .ptm.  -feat 1s_c_d_dd  -svspec 0-12/13-25/26-38  -cmn current  -agc none  -dictfn cmudict-en-us.dict  -ctlfn arctic20.fileids  -lsnfn arctic20.transcription  -accumdir en-us             "INFO: feat.c(715): Initializing feature stream to type: '1s_c_d_dd', ceplen=13, CMN='batch', VARNORM='no', AGC='none'
INFO: main.c(255): Using subvector specification 0-12/13-25/26-38
INFO: main.c(318): Reading en-us/mdef.txt"  and then it aborts  saying

Comment: "Debug Assertion Failed"      Program:D:\sphinx\sphinxbase\bin\Debug\x64\bw.exe    File:minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\lowio\read.cpp         Expression:_osfile(fh) & FOPEN

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, you need sphinxtrain and pocketsphinx for adaptation.

Comment: trying to run command bw -hmmdir en-us -moddeffn en-us/mdef.txt -ts2cbfn .ptm. -feat 1s_c_d_dd -svspec 0-12/13-25/26-38 -cmn current -agc none -dictfn cmudict-en-us.dict -ctlfn arctic20.fileids -lsnfn arctic20.transcription -accumdir en-us "INFO: feat.c(715): Initializing feature stream to type: '1s_c_d_dd', ceplen=13, CMN='batch', VARNORM='no', AGC='none' INFO: main.c(255): Using subvector specification 0-12/13-25/26-38 INFO: main.c(318): Reading en-us/mdef.txt" and then it aborts saying  
"Debug Assertion Failed"

Comment: Program:D:\sphinx\sphinxbase\bin\Debug\x64\bw.exe File:minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\lowio\read.cpp Expression:_osfile(fh) & FOPEN                                                     is there anything wrong in the arguments in the above command? i have tried it multiple times but always getting the same error